# Exception when calling database functions from anothe class

Tags: android

```
public class DatabaseManipulation extends Activity {
    public void updatingBookdetails(String fileName, Uri address) {
        String strAddress = address.toString();
        System.out.println(fileName + "  filename in updation"); // this prints
        System.out.println(strAddress + "  address in updation"); // this prints

        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("epub.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null); // error occurs here
        try {
            System.out.println("BLOW FILE111");
            db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
            db.setLockingEnabled(true);
            db.setVersion(1);






            System.out.println("BLOW FILE222");

            ContentValues val = new ContentValues();
            val.put("bookpath", fileName);
            val.put("lastchapter", strAddress);
            db.update("Bookdetails", val, "bookpath=" + fileName, null);
            System.out.println("BLOW FILE333");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e + "  errors happens");
        } finally {
            db.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling this from another activity which extends Web Activity.
The file name and `Uri` Address are passed from that activity say `X.class` to `DatabaseManipulation.class`
Please help

Logcat

```
03-03 14:20:50.294: E/AndroidRuntime(9955): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-03 14:20:50.294: E/AndroidRuntime(9955): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.dteviot.epubviewer/com.dteviot.epubviewer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-03 14:20:50.294: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2980)
    03-03 14:20:50.294: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3023)
    03-03 14:20:50.294: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:123)
    03-03 14:20:50.294: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1177)
    03-03 14:20:50.294: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-03 14:20:50.294: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    03-03 14:20:50.294: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    03-03 14:20:50.294: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-03 14:20:50.294: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    03-03 14:20:50.294: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
    03-03 14:20:50.294: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
    03-03 14:20:50.294: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-03 14:20:50.294: E/AndroidRuntime(9955): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-03 14:20:50.294: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:215)
    03-03 14:20:50.294: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at com.dteviot.epubviewer.DatabaseManipulation.updatingBookdetails(DatabaseManipulation.java:25)
    03-03 14:20:50.294: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at com.dteviot.epubviewer.EpubWebView.loadChapter(EpubWebView.java:196)
    03-03 14:20:50.294: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at com.dteviot.epubviewer.MainActivity.loadEpub(MainActivity.java:257)
    03-03 14:20:50.294: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at com.dteviot.epubviewer.MainActivity.onListEpubResult(MainActivity.java:241)
    03-03 14:20:50.294: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at com.dteviot.epubviewer.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:220)
    03-03 14:20:50.294: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4649)
    03-03 14:20:50.294: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2976)
    03-03 14:20:50.294: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: What is the error? Can you post logcat?

Comment: we will feel like in heaven if exception is pasted here

Comment: Can you provide your logcat?

Comment: @Szymon i have posted the logcat above

Answer (score 1):

Your `DatabaseManipulation` class is an `Activity` but it really isn't. You cannot use it as a `Context` this way.

Remove the `extends Activity`. Pass in a valid `Context` (such as `this` in an `Activity`) as an argument to `updatingBookdetails()` and call `openOrCreateDatabase()` on the argument.

Comment: can you please show me how it is done, because i am new to android.

Comment: Argument-passing is quite fundamental skill in Java programming. Search for "java method arguments" if you need detailed help with it.

Comment: i called the method as dbManipulation.updatingBookdetails(sentFilename, extraUri_start);

Answer (score 0):

make the function static and change where needed
then call the function from class like this DatabaseManipulation. updatingBookdetails(fileName, address);

Comment: i did called the function as you mentioned.
Also when i changed it to static openorcreatedatabase is showing error

Answer (score 0):

Use following code.

Replace below line

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase("epub.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
```

to

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase("epub.db", YourActivity.this.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
```

Comment: same error
Here is what i did
db = openOrCreateDatabase("epub.db", DatabaseManipulation.this.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
MODE_PRIVATE is shown as a warning