# null pointer exception when passing strin value from one class to another and initializing db there

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

```
//packages
//imports
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
 // some string declarations;
 // object creations etc etc
     DatabaseManipulation dbManage = new DatabaseManipulation();//whereDatabaseManipulation is a class bdManage -->object
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //creating contentViews;
}

 public void methods()
 {
 //works
 }
  public void methods2(String name)
  {
   try{
  dbManage.functioncall(name);
      }
   catch(Exception e)
      {
        System.out.println(e);// value of e is NullPointerException
      }
   }


}
```

And the Second class is DatabaseManipulation.class Which is given below

```
public class DatabaseManipulation extends Activity
{

  public void functioncall(String name)
 {

    System.out.println(bookName+ "  bookname in addBookmark");

      SQLiteDatabase db;
      db = openOrCreateDatabase("epub.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);// error occurs here
      db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
      db.setLockingEnabled(true);
      db.setVersion(1);

      String temp_address="nothing";


      try
      {
          String selectQuery = "SELECT lastchapter FROM Bookdetails WHERE bookpath=?";
          Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { name });
          if (c.moveToFirst()) {
              temp_address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lastchapter")); // assigning value in lastchapter to temp_address
          }
          System.out.println(temp_address+" result of select Query");  // 
      }

  catch(Exception e)
      {
       System.out.println(e);
      }

      try
      {



      System.out.println("BLOW FILE111");



      System.out.println("BLOW FILE222");
      final String createtabBook="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BookMark(lid INTEGER UNIQUE AUTOINCREMENT,  bookpath TEXT , lastchapter TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(bookpath,lastchapter));";
      db.execSQL(createtabBook);


      ContentValues val=new ContentValues();
      val.put("bookpath",name );
      val.put("lastchapter", temp_address);
     db.insert("Bookdetails", val, "bookpath="+name, null);
      System.out.println("BLOW FILE333");
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          System.out.println(e+"  errors happens");
      }
      finally
      {
          db.close();
      }

}

}
```

i just want to call this function from main activity to DatabaseManipulation.java, what am i doing wrong?
in log cat Null pointer exception is shown as the error, because i called it in try catch
can we actually do this type of function call? please help

Comment: where you are extending Activity in DatabaseManipulation class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception when calling database functions from anothe class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141872/exception-when-calling-database-functions-from-anothe-class)

Answer (score 4):

You can't instantiate an activity like this:

```
DatabaseManipulation dbManage = new DatabaseManipulation();
```

You need to use an Intent. Something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DatabaseManipulation.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: will startActivityforResult bring control back to MainActivity

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize your database class before your

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

method. Make global variable for your Database class

```
DatabaseManipulation dbManage;
```

and initiailize it after on onCreate() method after

```
setContentView(R.layout.urlayout)
```

method.

```
dbManage = new DatabaseManipulation();
```

Comment: i did like what u said but still same error, the place where db is initializing